# Lightning development help with component refresh

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created my custom related component for custom object on Contact detail page. It has two options edit and delete. On edit I am opening standard lightning edit page of the record and after saving the record I want to refresh my component. Following is my code for refresh

> aura:dependency resource="markup://force:recordSaveSuccess"
>   type="EVENT,COMPONENT" />   aura:handler name="handleSaveSuccess"
>   event="force:recordSaveSuccess" action="{!c.doInit}" />

This make sure that when Contact record is updated my component is refreshed but when custom object is edited using my edit button component is not getting refreshed.

Can you help me out with this.

```
<aura:component controller="acons100.LTN_ContactRolesController" 
            implements='force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasSObjectName'>

    <aura:attribute name="recordId"  type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />

    <aura:attribute name="acons100__Investor_Contact_Role__c" 
                    type="List" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="acons100__Investing_Entity_Contact_Role__c" 
                    type="List" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="investorContactlist"  
                    type="acons100__Investor_Contact_Role__c[]" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="entityContactlist"  
                    type="acons100__Investing_Entity_Contact_Role__c[]" access="global"/>

<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:editRecord" type="EVENT,COMPONENT" />
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:recordSaveSuccess" type="EVENT,COMPONENT" />
    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:handler name="handleSaveSuccess" event="force:recordSaveSuccess" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<!-- Will  be called on Component Load -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 

<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.sObjectName == 'Contact' || v.sObjectName == 'Account'}">
        <div style="margin:10px 10px 10px 10px">
            <div class="slds-m-top--medium">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size--12-of-12 slds-card">
                    <header class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-media slds-media--center">
                            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                                <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="Investor Contact Roles">
                                    <acons100:svg svgPath="/resource/acons100__SLDS100/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account"
                                           class="slds-icon" category="standard" size="small">
                                    </acons100:svg>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-media__body">
                                <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small">Investor Contact Roles ({!v.investorContactlist.length})</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                                    <button onclick="{!c.newInvestorContactRole}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" type="button">
                                        <span class="label bBody truncate" dir="ltr">New Investor Contact Role</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sObjectName == 'Account'}">
                                        <button onclick="{!c.newContact}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" type="button">
                                            <span class="label bBody truncate" dir="ltr">New Investor Contact</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </aura:if>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <section class="slds-card__body">
                        <table id="oppTable" 
                           class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal">
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.investorContactlist.length > 0}">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="slds-no-hover">
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sObjectName == 'Contact'}">
                                            <th class="slds-text-heading--label slds-is-resizable  slds-is-sortable"
                                                scope="col">Investor</th>
                                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                                <th class="slds-text-heading--label slds-is-resizable  slds-is-sortable"
                                                    scope="col">Contact</th>
                                            </aura:set>
                                        </aura:if>
                                        <th class="slds-text-heading--label slds-is-resizable  slds-is-sortable"
                                            scope="col">Role</th>
                                        <th class="slds-text-heading--label slds-is-resizable  slds-is-sortable"
                                            scope="col">Email</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <aura:iteration var="investor" items="{!v.investorContactlist}" indexVar="i">
                                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sObjectName == 'Contact'}">
                                                <td  data-label="Investor">
                                                    <a aura:id="investorId" href="{! '#/sObject/' + investor.acons100__Investor__c +'/view'}">
                                                        {!investor.acons100__Investor__r.Name}
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                                    <td  data-label="Contact">
                                                        <a aura:id="contactId" href="{! '#/sObject/' + investor.acons100__Contact__c +'/view'}">
                                                            {!investor.acons100__Contact__r.Name}
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </aura:set>
                                            </aura:if>
                                            <td  data-label="Role" >{!investor.acons100__Role__c}</td>
                                            <td  data-label="Email" >{!investor.acons100__Email_Formula__c}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="slds-float--right">
                                                    <div class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click"  
                                                     aura:id="investorDropDown" 
                                                     aria-expanded="true">
                                                        <button data-record="{!investor.Id}" 
                                                            onclick="{!c.openEditDelete}" 
                                                            class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border slds-button--icon-x-small" 
                                                            aria-haspopup="true">
                                                            <acons100:svg value="{!investor.Id}" 
                                                                   svgPath="/resource/acons100__SLDS100/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down"
                                                                   name="down" size="x-small"
                                                                   ariaHidden="true" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--hint slds-button__icon--small">
                                                            </acons100:svg>
                                                            <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--right">
                                                                <ul class="dropdown__list"  role="menu" aria-labelledby="editdelete">
                                                                    <li class="slds-dropdown__item">
                                                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                                                                           role="menuitem"
                                                                           data-record="{!investor.Id}"
                                                                           onclick="{!c.editContactRole}">
                                                                            <p class="slds-truncate">Edit</p>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li class="slds-dropdown__item">
                                                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
                                                                           role="menuitem"
                                                                           data-index="{!i}" 
                                                                           onclick="{!c.deleteInvestorContactRole}">
                                                                            <p class="slds-truncate">Delete</p>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                                </tbody>
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                            <td colspan="7">No records to display.</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                        </table>
                    </section>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.investorContactlist.length > 0}">
                        <section class="slds-card__footer" style="text-align:left;">
                            <ui:outputURL value="" label="View All" click="{!c.navigateToInvestorRoles}"/>
                        </section>
                    </aura:if>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:renderIf>
</aura:component>
```

Controller method calling edit method

```
editContactRole : function(component, event, helper) {
        var record = event.currentTarget.dataset.record;
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": record
        });
        editRecordEvent.fire();

        var cmpEvent = component.getEvent("refreshafterCustomEdit");
        cmpEvent.fire();
    }
openEditDelete : function(component,event,helper){
$A.util.toggleClass(event.currentTarget.parentNode,'slds-is-open');
}
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Hi Praveen, which part of the code do you want to see? . It is custom related list on which I have used the above mentioned code for re-rendering. I have designed using https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/#flavor-related-list-with-table this code.

Comment: Can you check the code and let me know. I have updated the code. After successfully finishing the editing contact role I want to refresh detail page on which the component is loaded.

Comment: Can you remove *name* attribute in force:recordSaveSuccess's *aura:handler* and check it

Comment: Because application event's(force: recordSaveSuccess) handler won't fire if name attribute specified in the aura:handler's markup

Comment: Hi Praveen, I removed that part of code. Now when I do standard edit the related lists are getting refreshed but when I when I click on custom edit button(of the above component) make changed and save the record the related list is not getting refreshed.

Comment: Are you trying to call the doInit using refreshafterCustomEdit event?.Also there is no `<aura:registerEvent name="refreshafterCustomEdit" ...>` markup in the above component which enables you to fire the event.

Comment: I tried that but it was not working. I had registered that event for refreshing the related list. Problem being it was getting called before the finish if save. That is moment I was opening edit mailout the refresh was getting called. I have removed that from the latest code.

Comment: Ok I tried it at my end, It didn't work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43334/discussion-between-shankish-and-praveen).

Comment: Only way i can think of is using `<force:recordEdit />` component in a SLDS modal instead of using `force:recordEdit` event and set the recordId dynamically.So I renders the edit view of the record and handle the save on your own.Here the link to for it https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_recordSaveSuccess.htm

Comment: Instead of relying on the `force:recordSaveSuccess`, if you attach handler for `force:refreshView` it would work.But there's a caveat in this approach, `force:refreshView` event fires on multiple instances; for example: if you use standard edit in record detail component/ related list component on completion of save, `force:refreshView` event fires which might refresh you component.

Comment: Currently I am using <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" /> for refreshing but this is not refreshing my custom component. :(

Comment: If possible can you update the question with the code you tried using force:refreshView

Comment: This might help : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159482/callback-event-on-a-gete-forceeditrecord-in-lightning/228565#228565