# Callback event on $A.get('e.force:editRecord') in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-events

I'm using $A.get('e.force:editRecord') to display standard lightning edit modal window. I want to refresh my component after user saves the given record.

However there are no callback events documented by salesforce on record save success for e.force:editRecord.

By using chrome Lightning inspector tool I found two events getting fired when I clicked on Save button.

```
1. force:recordChange (Application Event)
2. force:save (Component Event)
```

I declared an application event handler for **force:recordChange**

```
<aura:handler event="force:recordChange" action="{!c.handleRecordChange}"/>
```

Got following error

[ERROR]: No EVENT named recordChange found: Source

To handle component event **force:save** I have to specify event name

```
<aura:handler name="?" event="force:save" action="{!c.handleRecordSave}"/>
```

How do I notify custom component when user saves the record.

Comment: To refresh a view, run `$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();`, which reloads all data for the view.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can use `force:refreshView` for that but I think the event you're looking for is `force:recordSaveSuccess`. Doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_recordSaveSuccess.htm

Comment: @Soham did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You can inject your handler by using

```
component.addEventHandler("force:recordChange", component.getReference("c.handlEvent"));
```

It will work, but you can't prevent any 'default' phase events that you will catch

Comment: That's a great idea

Answer (score 3):

Been looking for such solution for a while. Seems like I'm not the only one and currently I had to settle for a workaround - I know it's not pretty and might be considered as kinda of a hack - but it's working.

In my Parent component I've placed :

```
 <!-- toast capture the RecordEdit Success/Warning notifications events  -->
 <aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.refreshAll}"/>

 <!-- My Child component that need to be refreshed from server -->
 <c:myChildComponent  rootObjectId="{!v.recordId}" aura:id="compGroup"/>
```

Parent JS Controller

```
refreshAll: function (component, event, helper) {
        var eventType = event.getParam('type');
        var indexCall = 0; // to make it call only 1 time
        if(eventType == 'SUCCESS'){
        if(indexCall == 0){
            indexCall +=1;
         var myComp = component.find('compGroup');
         if(myComp)
         var auraMethodResult = myComp.refresh();    
        }
       }
    },
```

Child Component Method

```
   <aura:attribute name="rootObjectId" type="String" description="root record Id"/>
   <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" description="results records"/>

   <aura:method name="refresh" action="{!c.refreshResults}" access="public">
            <aura:attribute name="rootObjectId" type="String" />
    </aura:method>
```

Child JS controller - calls Apex Method action to get new fresh data

```
  // init any value which need to be refreshed     
  refreshResults: function(component, event, helper)  {
       var rootObjectId = component.get("v.rootObjectId");
        var action = component.get("c.getMyData");
        action.setParams({ 
                'contextId': rootObjectId
            });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") { 
                var data = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());

            }
        }
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

I can solve it using

$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();

and later, when the view is refreshed, you can "delete" browser calls calling the same url plus some random param. Something like that

```
 var idObject= component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({ id : component.get("v.recordId") });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){           
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
                 setTimeout(function() {
                 $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                     setTimeout(function() {
                        var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
                        var chars = "0123456789abcdefABCDEF";
                        var lon = 20;
                        var code = "";
                        for (var x=0; x < lon; x++)
                        {
                            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length);
                            code += chars.substr(rand, 1);
                        }
                        window.location.href=url+'?uncached='+code; 
                     }, 2000);                
                }, 3000);
            }   
        });       
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: Can you please add a bit more explanation?

Comment: `setTimeout` should be a last option as in future you would want to have more control over on whats exactly is going on.

Comment: LOL to make it worse this is a double timeout

Comment: The whole situation is:

I need a Quick Action which call Google Maps API with a Direction for get Coordenades. This is the action called from callback;

I wait for three seconds for the Webservice, and for the update operation. After three seconds I refresh the view.

Finally I wait two seconds for the view refresh, and refresh the whole page without cache calling the same URL adding the random param.