# How to save $A.get("e.force:editRecord"); and not go to the record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to use the standard layout for creating and editing records within my lightning component.

I don't want the user to leave the page that he is in (one page application...)

So I want to implement a popup for editing and creating these records, I am trying to use$A.get("e.force:editRecord"):

```
editRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = component.get("v.id");

    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": recordId
    });
    editRecordEvent.fire();
},
```

The problem that I encounter is that after the user clicks on the `Save` button in the popup, the page is redirected to the record that was edited or created.

I cannot find a way to cancel this redirection. [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159482/callback-event-on-a-gete-forceeditrecord-in-lightning) question asks how to capture the save event. Although it is related to my problem, it not the same and there is no solution there.

So can I cancel the redirection after saving?

Comment: There is an undocumented solution for that, check my answer here: [Lightning force:createRecord capture redirect after save](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198168/lightning-forcecreaterecord-capture-redirect-after-save/203535#203535)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far it's not possible.

If you have access to the Partner Community, I asked about this [here](https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009NQx&fId=0D53A000034xveM) but it was not on the roadmap for now.

An idea has been created recently for it, so I would suggest to go and vote for it [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003VnmQAE).

Comment: Thanks @FabienTailon - I have given up on this long time ago, and it is still not possible...