# Is it possible to prevent sforce.one.createRecord() and $A.get("e.force:createRecord") from navigating to the new record?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, navigation, sforce, sforce-one

**Is this a duplicate?**

This is not an duplicate of [Lightning force:createRecord capture redirect after save](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198168/lightning-forcecreaterecord-capture-redirect-after-save)

because I'm additionally looking for a solution primarily for VF an not only LC. I can't use "panelOnDestroyCallback" directly, even if it would work. Trying this even worse hack instead also failed and the console.log will be never reached:

```
SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.fireContainerEvent(
    "force:createRecord"
  , { entityApiName: 'Account'
        , "panelOnDestroyCallback": function(event) { 
               console.log('TEST') 
        }  
  } 
);
```

So the question is similar, but not the same.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm using sforce.one.createRecord() in VF and $A.get("e.force:createRecord") in LCs to get a popup for creating new records it works fine in both worlds even with the feature to prepopulate default values, e.g. like this

```
sforce.one.createRecord( 
      objectName 
    , null
    , { parentLookupFieldName : parentRecordId } 
);
```

Basic use case is to overcome the limits of the Standard Related List components, such as limit to 4 columns, card-mode in narrow columns instead of table-mode and much more limits we have in LEX right now.

Rest assured, that `objectName`, `parentLookupFieldName` and `parentRecordId` are fine. In LEX it looks:

This sits on a Record Flexipage. Instead of the VF version, it could also be a LC firing `$A.get("e.force:createRecord")` with practically the same outcome.

[image]

Now after clicking on SAVE, the platform reroutes me to the new record.

This rerouting might be a feature in **some** scenarios, but for sure this is **NOT OK** for my process. Instead I need to stick at the record, from where I have hammered the "New" button. I must not leave that record on the UI, but I need to reload (or refresh) the record in order to make the new record appear in the related list.

Now I doubt that this is supported in a "straight forward" manner, but I would be happy to hack something, e.g. navigate back to the original record or whatever.

Has anybody an idea on how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lightning force:createRecord capture redirect after save](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198168/lightning-forcecreaterecord-capture-redirect-after-save)

Comment: I don't have time to test the theory but you might be able to register a handler in your component for `aura:applicationEvent` or `force:recordSaveSuccess` or `force:afterRecordSave` and then stop the event's normal behavior of redirecting by leveraging `event.preventDefault()` and then your handler can fire a `force:refreshView` event to refresh the page.