# I have scenario where i am using $A.get('e.force:createRecord')

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When i click on Save button i do not want the page to be redirected to to object detail page.I want to be on same page where me performing the action.How this can be achieved in lightning .I tried to use `event.preventDefault()`.But it is not working.

Comment: Hey, Please add more details. Your question is not quite clear. What you have tried with minimal piece of code?

Comment: You would like to see the answer here -
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198168/lightning-forcecreaterecord-capture-redirect-after-save

Answer (score 0):

Using $A.get('e.force:createRecord') is not possible to customise save/submit.

But I can suggest an alternative approach.

**Step 1 :** First create a lighting component lets say **Comp1** using **lightning:recordForm**. Here, you can customise **onsubmit** handler the way you want.

**Step 2 :** Use lightning:overlayLibrary to dynamically open **Comp1** as a modal.

**Step 3 :** replace $A.get('e.force:createRecord').fire() with below code.

```
  $A.createComponent("Comp1", {},
       function(content, status) {
           if (status === "SUCCESS") {
               modalBody = content;
               component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                   header: "Create Record",
                   body: modalBody, 
                   showCloseButton: true,
                   cssClass: "mymodal",
                   closeCallback: function() {
                       //alert('You closed the alert!');
                   }
               })
           }                               
       });
```

If you would like my suggestion you can mark it as an answer.