# Callback on "e.force:editRecord" Lightning Event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-events, callback

I have a page listing Cases with an edit button assigned to each one - the edit button fires a standard e.force:editRecord event, passing the recordId per button.

Is there a way I can run a function/action on save of this record in order to refresh/rerun the Case list?

I have looked at the following answers but they do not work.
[Callback event on $A.get('e.force:editRecord') in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159482/callback-event-on-a-gete-forceeditrecord-in-lightning)

Example code:

This is where I am attempting to handle the events:

```xml
<aura:handler name="handleEdit" event="force:editRecord" action="{!c.fetchCaseRows}" />
<aura:handler name="handleSaveSuccess" event="force:recordSaveSuccess" action="{!c.fetchCaseRows}" />
```

This is where I call the save:

```javascript
updateCase: function(component, event, helper) {
    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": event.currentTarget.id
    });
    editRecordEvent.fire();
},
```

Comment: is this component part of a vf page/ record detail page in lightning /lightning tab ?

Comment: This is a Lightning Component/Tab.

Comment: can you post your code to see how you are trying to call the refresh event/savesuccess event if you tried that route

Comment: I have updated the original post.

Neither event fires.

Comment: is this a copy paste error? your events are calling fetchcaseRows from the client side controller and all I see in the client side is updateCase function?

Comment: I only copied the save function. The fetcCaseRows function is simple a method that runs on init, and that I want to rerun on save which pulls down all the rows. I just need a way to call the method when the record saves so it does not navigate to the new record.

Comment: I understand ur concept but not the approach. Assuming forcerefreshview is not working as expected, have you tried window.location.reload() on the updatecase method, i have had issues refreshing the view using force.refreshview.

Comment: It isn't that the forcerefreshview is not working, it is the fact that I cannot run any callback on the successful save of a record. Regardless of the callback function provided to the handleEdit/handleSaveSuccess handlers, the page always redirects to the updated record - I wish to override this and provide my own callback.

Comment: Just a thought, have you thought of using 'force:recordData' component i.e. lightning data api to maintain sync of data?

Comment: Merge suggestion with : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159482/callback-event-on-a-gete-forceeditrecord-in-lightning/228565#228565