# Can we reload screen after Save from force:editRecord event?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, callback

I've a Custom `Lightning Component` displaying a `List` custom object records.

On each data row, I've custom button to `Edit` the record.

On `Edit` click, I've fired following event:

```
var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
editRecordEvent.setParams({
     "recordId": component.get("v.item.Id")
});
editRecordEvent.fire();
```

Now, this does open the Edit modal dialog for the record, but After we have Saved, it does not Refresh the list of record I have in the display.

Is there any way I can trap the Save event and reload my Component data after we Save any record from the list?

Comment: Merge Suggestion with : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159482/callback-event-on-a-gete-forceeditrecord-in-lightning/228565#228565

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly if this would work but you can take a look at the `force:recordSaveSuccess` event type. Here is a link to the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_recordSaveSuccess.htm

Answer (score 0):

After providing you are using a custom component you can just set up a `init` method which is called when the component is loaded. When you save your record, you can fire the same controller method again.

If you need to redirect the user to the record, you use `force:navigateToSObject`:

```
$A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject").setParams({
    "recordId": recordId ,
    "slideDevName": "detail"
}).fire()
```

But if you just need to reload a record view, you use `force:refreshView`:

```
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. I was not able to Refresh the page after save but at least I can Redirect to the page where the records is created using location.href

```
var windowRedirect = window.location.href; // Current Page URL

var createEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createEvent.setParams({
    "entityApiName": 'Custom_Object__c',
    "recordTypeId": RecTypeID, 
    "defaultFieldValues": {
        "Opportunity__c": oppId
    },
    "panelOnDestroyCallback": function(event) {
        window.location.href = windowRedirect; // Return to the page where the record was created
    }
});
createEvent.fire();
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but this approach seems certain to violate the LockerService paradigm, even if it is allowed. I would think proper lightning navigation would use `force:navigateToUrl` or something similar.